# calloc, malloc, free and realloc wrappers to store the size being allocated

Tags: c++, node.js, memory-management, curl

I'm currently building a node.js addon for libcurl. Right now I'm trying to correctly use `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory` to update v8 on the amount of memory being allocated by libcurl, and to do that I need to wrap the above mentioned functions that libcurl uses, using [`curl_global_init_mem()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init_mem.html).

I saw the following code being used [here](https://github.com/gagern/libxmljs/blob/master/src/libxmljs.cc#L77) that basically does the same thing, but for another lib.

I currently have the following code (almost identical to the one above):

```
struct MemWrapper {
    size_t size;
    double data;
};

#define MEMWRAPPER_SIZE offsetof( MemWrapper, data )

inline void* MemWrapperToClient( MemWrapper* memWrapper ) {
    return static_cast<void*>( reinterpret_cast<char*>( memWrapper ) + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE );
}

inline MemWrapper* ClientToMemWrapper( void* client ) {
    return reinterpret_cast<MemWrapper*>( static_cast<char*>( client ) - MEMWRAPPER_SIZE );
}

void AdjustMem( ssize_t diff )
{
    Nan::AdjustExternalMemory( static_cast<int>( diff ) );
}

void* MallocCallback( size_t size )
{
    size_t totalSize = size + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE;
    MemWrapper* mem = static_cast<MemWrapper*>( malloc( totalSize ) );
    if ( !mem ) return NULL;
    mem->size = size;
    AdjustMem( totalSize );
    return MemWrapperToClient( mem );
}

void FreeCallback( void* p )
{
    if ( !p ) return;
    MemWrapper* mem = ClientToMemWrapper( p );
    ssize_t totalSize = mem->size + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE;
    AdjustMem( -totalSize );
    free( mem );
}

void* ReallocCallback( void* ptr, size_t size )
{
    if ( !ptr ) return MallocCallback( size );
    MemWrapper* mem1 = ClientToMemWrapper( ptr );
    ssize_t oldSize = mem1->size;
    MemWrapper* mem2 = static_cast<MemWrapper*>( realloc( mem1, size + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE ) );
    if ( !mem2 ) return NULL;
    mem2->size = size;
    AdjustMem( ssize_t( size ) - oldSize );
    return MemWrapperToClient( mem2 );
}

char* StrdupCallback( const char* str )
{
    size_t size = strlen( str ) + 1;
    char* res = static_cast<char*>( MallocCallback( size ) );
    if ( res ) memcpy( res, str, size );
    return res;
}

void* CallocCallback( size_t nmemb, size_t size )
{
    size_t totalSize = size + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE;
    MemWrapper* mem = static_cast<MemWrapper*>( calloc( nmemb, totalSize ) );
    if ( !mem ) return NULL;
    mem->size = nmemb * size;
    AdjustMem( nmemb * totalSize );
    return MemWrapperToClient( mem );
}
```

I hook it up with libcurl calling:

```
curl_global_init_mem( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL, MallocCallback, FreeCallback, ReallocCallback, StrdupCallback, CallocCallback );
```

I compiled the add-on, and from what I can see, it's working fine, but as I'm unexperienced with C++, I need to know if this is correct. What kind of bad things can happen from modifying the pointer returned by `calloc`, `malloc` and `prealloc` like that? Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: One word: Alignment. Is `ptr + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE` correctly aligned for objects of size `size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of [the code you mentioned](https://github.com/gagern/libxmljs/blob/62d8b125eae6ca92208c859967bd226ff10dcb97/src/libxmljs.cc#L77), with [some suggestions](https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/pull/300#discussion_r28355793) by [Nathan Zadoks](https://github.com/nathan7). I've used the same idea in [another project](https://github.com/gagern/node-libtidy/blob/0b017e41fc65a3c3193fd410d6d35274d7bb7f71/src/memory.cc). So any mistakes others may find in the copied code will likely affect my code as well.

### async?

One critical question is whether you intend to perform asynchroneous operations. If so, this code will likely fail because `Nan::AdjustExternalMemory` has to be called from the main Node thread, i.e. must not be called from a worker thread.

### calloc

The `CallocCallback` is wasteful. Your code allocates

```
nmemb * (size + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE)
```

while a better implementation would only allocate

```
(nmemb * size) + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE
```

You can't get that by delegating to `calloc`, though. Instead I'd build on `MallocCallback` like this (similar to how `StrdupCallback` works, too):

```
void* CallocCallback( size_t nmemb, size_t size )
{
    void* ptr = MallocCallback( nmemb * size );
    if (!ptr) return NULL;
    memset( ptr, 0, nmemb * size ); // zero-fill
    return ptr;
}
```

### alignment

Since Loki raised concerns regarding [alignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment), I'll explain my rationale.

Some platforms will suffer a performance penalty if certain data types are not aligned with memory addresses in a certain way, others may even prevent access, or pervent access for certain kins of operation ([like SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12502071/1468366)). I'm guessing that the largest data type affected by this *in the library in question* is probably `double`. So I'm using a `double` item as the `data` entry of the structure, and you copied that. If the compiler thinks alignment is important, it will lay out the struct in such a way that the `data` item is properly aligned if and only if the structure as a whole is properly aligned. It can accomplish this by introducing some padding between `size` and `data`.

So for example if `sizeof(size_t) == 4` but `sizeof(double) == 8` and more importantly `alignof(double) == 8`, then you'd get `sizeof(MemWrapper) == 16`, layed out as 4 bytes for `size`, 4 bytes padding, 8 bytes for `data`. You'd have `offsetof(MemWrapper, data) == 8`, taking both `size` and padding into account. The common calls like [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) will return memory which is properly aligned for any object type. So the wrapper will be aligned, and hence its data portion will be aligned as well.

The correct way to actually follow the `malloc` spec by the letter (instead of relying on some idea of what objects the library actually uses) would be using [`std::max_align_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t) (introduced in C++11) instead of `double`. But the difference becomes only important if the library is dealing in objects larger than a simple `double`. It might also be the case that the compiler doesn't pad the data structure by default, risking a performance impact or failure of some (e.g. SSE) operations. On GCC-like compilers [the `aligned` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) can be used to control alignment and prevent packing. A more portable way to achieve the same would probably be the use of an (anonymous) `union` between the `size` field and a `std::max_align_t` element. But I'd only do this if the application in question were using SSE or something like that, since on arhictectures where unaligned access is a more common problem I'd expect the compiler to take care of this.

Comment: About async, the wrappers are going to be added to libcurl only if it's built without the threaded resolver (the only thing that makes libcurl create another thread and call those functions from there). The addon itself doesn't call any of those functions.

And thank you for the alignment insight!

Answer (score 2):

1. Check alignment.

I don;t believe you are correctly aligning your objects.

<strike>2. Realloc is wrong.</strike>

if realloc returns `NULL` the original pointer is not deallocated.

```
MemWrapper* mem2 = static_cast<MemWrapper*>( realloc( mem1, size + MEMWRAPPER_SIZE ) );
if ( !mem2 ) return NULL;
```

Here if realloc fails you have just leaked memory (as `mem1` is still valid).

The standard usage pattern for realloc is:

```
 void* data = malloc(size);
 ...

 void* extra = realloc(data, newSize);
 if (extra) {
     data = extra;   // only reset data if the realloc worked.

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate more on ``correctly aligning your objects.``?

Comment: I don't follow your concerns about realloc. The way I see it, the semantics are delegated cleanly: if the inner `realloc` call returns `NULL`, then the outer `ReallocCallback` should return `NULL` as well. It's caller supposedly still holds the pointer it passed in, and can free that later on just as it would after a call to `realloc`.

Comment: @MvG: Yep that would make sense.